# ibmcloud:CIS: what is the meaning of TTL value is 'automatically'?

Tags: ibm-cloud

My TTL value is set to 'automatically' for a record, what is the meaning? How long is the record in the cache?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Taking DNS as an example.The TTL(time-to-live) will have a default value of Automatic but can be changed by the user. A proxied DNS record will always have a TTL of Automatic, so a newly proxied record will change to this configuration during this change.

> DNS change propagation times depend on the time-to-live (TTL) setting
>   for the DNS record.
>
> The default TTL is one day, which means any modifications to a domain
>   name take one day to propagate throughout the entire internet. TTL can
>   be lowered if you plan to make changes frequently, however, the lower
>   the TTL is, the higher the load becomes on the name server. Higher
>   loads have the potential to increase the response time to end users,
>   which could impact their overall satisfaction.
>
> The higher the TTL setting, the higher DNS performance will be due to
>   local ISP caching. The lower the TTL setting, the lower DNS
>   performance will be due to increased name resolution.
>
> To verify TTL, check the Start of Authority (SOA) record for the
>   domain. A great tool for reviewing domain information is offered by
>   CentralOps.net
>
> TTL is listed in seconds. Divide by 60 to convert TTL to minutes, or
>   by 3600 to convert to hours.

For browser Cache TTL, refer the CIS API docs [here](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/cis/cache#get-browser-cache-ttl-setting)